# Flex-Mobile: Should I use the menu-stuff provided or is it better not to because the iphone does not have a menu button?

Tags: iphone, android, ios, apache-flex, button

I would not have asked the question if I owned an iphone, but so far I only have an android phone for development.

The question is: Should I use the View.viewMenuItems that are provided by flex mobile? Or should I better embed the functionality in another way? I don't know what possibilities might exist on iphone to open the menu, because it has no hardware button "menu".

By the way: How could I open the menu in the Flash-Builder mobile device emulator - there are no buttons, too....

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can detect the Menu Button through KeyBoardEvent in Android. In Iphone, the Home Button will exit out your application, so you should do some interface buttons to show your menu.

```
            private function _onAddedToStage(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                //removes listener
                removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _onAddedToStage);
                stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, _onKeyDown);
            }

            private function _onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.MENU)
                {
                event.preventDefault();
                _text.appendText("\nMenu Pressed");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of Android's Honeycomb OS does not support the menu button.  So if you do take advantage of Flex's ViewMenu feature beware that if you build using Flex 4.6 or newer there won't be a button on the latest Android Tablets and iOS devices.

In ADL you can choose Device > Menu to simulate clicking a hardware menu button.